# How to prepopulate database with dummy entity data?

Tags: mysql, jpa, netbeans, maven

I'm building my first web application using JavaEE. I'm using Netbeans 7 and Maven. I've noticed that every time I make a change to my program it drops and re-creates the database. I want a way to populate the database with dummy data.

I tried using unit tests but that generated issues with the embedded.EBJContainer (errr.. something) and three days later I'm looking for another solution to my problem.

How should I provide dummy data for the database during development?
Is there a place in maven where I can specify a sql script to run where I can place insertion data?

Comment: It drops and recreates the db because that's what netbeans specifies in persistence.xml by default - see Table Generation Strategy.  That way you at least don't have to recreate the test db every time you run the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to take a look at [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) for database related testing. You can specify your initial data set in XML and it offers Maven integration too.

Comment: DBunit is the answer you're looking for. Another alternative is Liquibase which has the ability to manage a "test" context: http://www.liquibase.org/manual/contexts

Comment: The DBUnit link you posted goes to some Chinese site. Here is an updated link as at 19/12/2015: http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/